# PHP Cannot escape my string properly

Tags: php, mysql, string, escaping

I'm using `mysql_real_escape_string` to escape my content but I am receiving an error in a SQL INSERTION QUERY for having a single-quote unescaped. How can I resolve this?

```
$content = mysql_real_escape_string("'content'",$conn);
```

The error message I am receiving is:

```
You have an error in your sql syntax near 'content
```

My SQL Query ENDS UP BEING of the following:

```
$sql = "INSERT into `table` (`column`) VALUES ("'content'")
```

INSTEAD OF

```
$sql = "INSERT into `table` (`column`) VALUES ("\'content\'")
```

I also tried using single quotes for my delimiter and ended up failing on a double quote not being escaped.

Comment: You asked this question 5 minutes ago. We asked to provide some code snippet. Please.

Comment: Please quote your error messages in full.

Comment: An example string would be really helpful - what you're describing shouldn't be possible.

Comment: @Anodyne : except if the error is in another part of the SQL query ;-) Like the rest of the insert... Which is why people keep asking @Jonathan to provide a longer code portion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Like people said in your previous that you deleted, you need to give us more informations, like a full example that shows each steps of the construction of your query ; and, also you should give use the SQL query by itself, and the error message you get...*

Still, if you allow me quoting your previous question, you said your SQL query was the following :

```
insert into `exp_weblog_data` (`entry_id`,`site_id`,`weblog_id`,`field_id_117`,`field_ft_117`,`field_id_27`,`field_ft_27`,`field_id_26`,`field_ft_26`,`field_id_28`,`field_ft_28`,`field_id_129`,`field_ft_129`,`field_id_33`,`field_ft_33`) 
values ("","1","112","Patch 1.10","none","","none","- Fixed a bug with certain Creative Lab DVD drives and copy protection.("Unable to connect to Battle.net").","none","","none","ftp://totukati.gamezone.com/lodpatch_110.exe","none","[16020] Diablo II: Lord of Destruction","none")
```

If it is still that same query, strings in SQL must not be delimited by double quotes (`"`), but by simple quotes (`'`).

Which means your query should look a bit more like this :

```
insert into `exp_weblog_data` (`entry_id`,`site_id`,`weblog_id`,`field_id_117`,`field_ft_117`,`field_id_27`,`field_ft_27`,`field_id_26`,`field_ft_26`,`field_id_28`,`field_ft_28`,`field_id_129`,`field_ft_129`,`field_id_33`,`field_ft_33`) 
values ('','1','112','Patch 1.10','none','','none','- Fixed a bug with certain Creative Lab DVD drives and copy protection.("Unable to connect to Battle.net").','none','','none','ftp://totukati.gamezone.com/lodpatch_110.exe','none','[16020] Diablo II: Lord of Destruction','none')
```

Comment: @Jonathan : that (editing your other question) might have been a solution ;-)

Comment: @Pascal now I know not to redraft the same question :)